# How to extend my code by grouped and filtered data

Tags: r

I posted my question in a different post but unfotunately, I didn't get any answer, so I'm trying again after making some progress myself ... Here is an overview about my case :
I'm trying to analyse the effect of "Factor1" and "Factor2" on the response variable "perf" by "location", and obtaining at the end my original dataset associated to the lsmeans and tukey groups letters. Here below the code I'm using that gives me exactly what I need but only by location, my need is : how can I extend it in a way my output combines all locations, i.e, output of lsmeans and CLD by location :

```
library(multcomp)
library(lsmeans)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

output <- as.data.frame(dataset)
output$perf <- as.numeric(output$perf)
output$factor1 <- as.factor(output$factor1)
output$factor2 <- as.factor(output$factor2)
output <- output %>% 
           group_by(location) %>% 
           mutate(row=row_number()) 

model <- lm(perf ~ factor1 + factor2, data = output)
lsmeans <- lsmeans(model, ~ factor1)
CLD = cld(lsmeans,
            alpha   = 0.05,
            Letters = letters,
            adjust  = "tukey")         

output <- left_join(output, CLD, by = "factor1")
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You'll get better help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(dataset)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: @neilfws : thank you for your reply and for reviewing my previous post. I tried but didn't suceedd to add an extract of my dataset ...